# Display content with the same format i entered into the text area in java or jquery

Tags: java, jsp, textarea

I have a text area and enter some content in this text-area I want to display the content on jsp page in the same format in which I have entered the content in text-area. So its like I entered the text in text-area then save it in mysql database then retrieve it from database and display it on Jsp page. I google it also but can't find the solution.

I am using Spring MVC with mysql database.

Comment: What do you mean by "the same format"? Are you looking for some Ritch Text Editor?

Comment: And where exactly is your problem? What is wrong with what you have currently? What do you mean by "same format" exactly? HTML format? Plain text format with respect to newlines and spaces? You leave many open holes in your description.

Comment: Hi Tichodroma, I am not looking for rich text editor. @PhiLho if I press enter and write something on next line and if I create kind of paragraph by giving some spaces in my textarea then while displaying my content it should display in same format I entered

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enclose the text into a `pre` tag:

```
<pre><c:out value="${theTextFromDatabase}"/></pre>
```

The `c:out` JSTL tag is necessary to HTML-escape all the HTML special chars: `<` become `&lt;`, `>` becomes `&gt;`, `&` becomes `&amp;`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

i got the answer to remove the **Textarea** Problem,Now there is no need to add  Tag in Textarea.
just append the value which coming from textarea.like this.i did it & it is working well.

`String ques=request.getParameter("ques");
 StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
 sb.append("<pre>"+ques+"</pre>");
 String ss=sb.toString();`

Answer (score 0):

When you say in the same format you mean bold, italic, eol, and so on? The text is saved in your database with the format that you have introduced ? . I think that you need some kind of plugin wysiwyg ( what you see is what you get) like TinyMce (http://www.tinymce.com/) or save the correct format in your database and then process the text to format it according the text you received from your database.